# How do I handle errors in a children's application?

Tags: ipad, errors

I'm developing a children's learning app for preschoolers where the basic idea is that the parent hands the device to the child, and is free to then leave the room. I anticipate, of course, that the app will run as expected; however, on the off-chance something *does* go wrong, it will most likely affect the child's ability to learn and progress. Thus, in such an event, I may need to notify the parent as soon as possible. Some ways I have thought of to accomplish this are:
1) Have my app say "Uh-oh" or some other sound over the speakers
2) Send the parent an e-mail using the address listed in the corresponding Address Book entry.
In both cases, I would also show a message telling the parent what happened and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have some good ideas for getting the parents' attention (though unbidden loud sounds might be a little shocking). However it seems more than likely that the parent will not get an email immediately, nor will they be in the same room to hear the sound.

Perhaps **a very friendly, kid-centric message** in a banner or modal (depending on how drastic the situation is) that tells the child that something went wrong and asks the child to go get their parent will be a good addition to your ideas.